# Creating Associations in Rails using has_many and belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I know there are a lot of topics on this already but I couldn't find any that were what I'm trying to do. I'm just learning Rails and although I know this is probably a pretty simple fix, I'm stumped.

I'm creating a "Timeline" site. I have user accounts set up, and the user can create timelines. But, what I need to do is associate multiple timeline "events" (items to go in the timeline, the model for these is called Event) with each timeline (the model for which is called Timeline_Object). More plainly - a user has multiple timelines, and a timeline has multiple events.

The problem is that I can't get events set up with the timeline correctly. I think the association is set up correctly between users and timelines, but I'm not completely sure how to figure out what's wrong. Here are my models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :timeline_objects

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, 
  :remember_me, :user_name

end


class TimelineObject < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :user

    attr_accessible :title, :user_id

    has_many :events    

end


class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :timeline_object

    attr_accessible :date, :description, :time, :title, :image, 
    :image_width, :image_height, :timeline_objects
    has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :large => "500x500>", :medium => "400x400#", :thumb => "100x100>" }
    after_post_process :save_image_dimensions

    validates :title, presence: true
    validates :image, presence: true
    validates :time, presence: true
    validates :date, presence: true 

  def save_image_dimensions
    geo = Paperclip::Geometry.from_file(image.queued_for_write[:original])
    self.image_width = geo.width
    self.image_height = geo.height
  end
end
```

After running some migrations to set up the keys in the database, this is what my schema looks like:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20130402144923) do

  create_table "events", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "description"
    t.string   "date"
    t.string   "time"
    t.datetime "created_at",         :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",         :null => false
    t.string   "image_file_name"
    t.string   "image_content_type"
    t.integer  "image_file_size"
    t.datetime "image_updated_at"
    t.integer  "image_height"
    t.integer  "image_width"
    t.integer  "timeline_objects"
  end

  add_index "events", ["timeline_objects"], :name => "index_events_on_timeline_objects"

  create_table "timeline_objects", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end

  add_index "timeline_objects", ["user_id"], :name => "index_timeline_objects_on_user_id"

  create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "user_name"
    t.string   "email",                  :default => "", :null => false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     :default => "", :null => false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          :default => 0
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                             :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                             :null => false
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], :name => "index_users_on_email", :unique => true
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], :name => "index_users_on_reset_password_token", :unique => true

end
```

When I go to show the timeline (at which point all the events should be displayed), I try to loop through them with

```
<% @timeline_object.events.each do |event| %>
```

That line of code produces this error:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: events.timeline_object_id: SELECT "events".* FROM "events"  WHERE "events"."timeline_object_id" = 4
```

So I realize that means I'm missing something in my database, but I'm not sure what I should change/add to make it all work.

Let me know if you need any additional info/code. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Events schema, you have:

```
t.integer  "timeline_objects"
```

but, it should be:

```
t.integer  "timeline_object_id"
```

Run a new migration to fix it:

```
rename_column :events, :timeline_objects, :timeline_object_id
```

Since each event belongs to a TimelineObject, then it needs a column that identifies the id of the object that it's associated to.

Comment: That did it. I didn't realize it specifically had to be appended with _id. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Don't forget to update the index reference to timeline_object_id